# Is there a way to load a .DAT file in the MS SQL Sever table using ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a .DAT file in a ftp server. I have to load the data in a SQL table. I am trying to create datasets in ADF using this .DAT file using ftp as source and ADLS as sink. However it is not getting created. Please suggest how can this be done or if there are any alternatives

I tried loading the .DAT file to ADLS using file format as binary but I am unable to look at data.

If I use file format as csv then I cannot use comma, space, tab, blank space, etc. as delimiter and ADF requires me to enter a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken simple `.dat` file with month data and tried to transfer it into SQL server table followed below procedure:

Dataset setting:
[image]

Pipeline source settings:
[image]

Successful pipeline run:
[image]

> I tried loading the .DAT file to ADLS using file format as binary but I am unable to look at data.

You cannot transfer data by using Binary as source if you took binary as source your sink also should be binary format and SQL server table is not a binary format.

Comment: I cannot specify Tab as a delimiter when creating a dataset. My .DAT file does not has a delimiter. It is fixed length with no delimiter. I have to transform data from the file and do column mapping to load data in SQL Server table.

Comment: When the column delimiter is defined as empty string, which means no delimiter, the whole line is taken as a single column. Currently, column delimiter as empty string (No delimiter) is only supported for mapping data flow but not Copy activity.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use mapping data flow to have columns based number of characters and then load the data into table? For example, characters 1-10 go to column 1, next 15 characters go to column 2 and so on

Comment: Yes you can use derived colum transformation and then for every column take a substring